# cannot access objects inside service response

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, rest

When I tried to access the JSON response I cannot access the object.

I need to get the `target` and `datapoint` objects and after that I need to iterate the `dataPoint` array.

`result.target` is undefined in the above case.

Controller:

```
$scope.serviceCalls = function() {
    var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/rest/1";
    var promise = CommonService.getServiceJSON(serviceUrl);
    promise.then(function(result) {
        $scope.jsondata = result;
        console.log($scope.jsondata); // getting the JSON in console logs
        console.log($scope.jsondata.target); //returns undefined 
    }, function(reason) {
        alert('Failed: ' + reason);
    }, function(update) {
        alert('Got notification: ' + update);
    });
}
```

JSON response that I am receiving:

```
[{
    "target": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "datapoints": [
        [14711037952.0, 1474340220],
        [14711058432.0, 1474340280],
        [14719434752.0, 1474361700],
        [null, 1474361760]
    ]
}]
```

Comment: `$scope.jsondata[0].target` - result is an array. Also make sure that result is a Json and not string (else use JSON.parse(result) to parse it)

Comment: thank you.
I have missed the fact that its an array JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response is an array, so you have to use an index.

Example

```
console.log($scope.jsondata[0].target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$scope.jsondata = JSON.parse(result);`

Answer (score 0):

Use an index to go through the data:

$scope.jsondata[0].target

Answer (score 0):

$scope.jsondata is an array

```
$scope.jsondata[0].target will give you target
$scope.jsondata[0].datapoints will give you required array
```